# JMS XA Transactions with ActiveMQ and Spring JtaTransactionManager: The session has already been closed

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, xa

I have a Spring 4.2 application running on Wildfly 8.2 using ActiveMQ 5.10.2 and Postgres 9.3 in an XA configuration.

Everything seems to work fine apart from one thing.
When the XA transaction commits I get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The session has already been closed
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.safeGetSessionHolder(PooledSession.java:482) [activemq-all-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.getInternalSession(PooledSession.java:382) [activemq-all-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.commit(PooledSession.java:167) [activemq-all-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
at org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsResourceHolder.commitAll(JmsResourceHolder.java:184) [spring-jms-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$JmsResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:421) [spring-jms-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$JmsResourceSynchronization.processResourceAfterCommit(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:404) [spring-jms-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.ResourceHolderSynchronization.afterCommit(ResourceHolderSynchronization.java:85) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:958) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:803) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
```

The reason for this is that the commit itself is fine and this closes the ActiveMQ session but as can be seen from the stack trace above, AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit ends up calling PolledSession.commit again and this throws the IllegalStateException since the session is already closed.

There appears to be no setting that would modify this behaviour and the transaction does actually commit so its more annoying that anything else.

This would seem more of an issue on the Spring side for calling commit twice. The ActiveMQ driver looks to be behaving in a reasonable manner.

Comment: Excellent observation! I am facing similar issue while writing junit. Please share if you have found any solution to this.